# How to make Prettier to ignore a block of code?

Tags: javascript, prettier

Say we have a line of code:

```js
const a = 'a'; const b = 'b';
```

and we wouldn't want it to be formatter by Prettier.

What I've tried so far:

1)

```js
// prettier-ignore
const a = 'a'; const b = 'b';
```

2. 

```js
// prettier-ignore-start
const a = 'a'; const b = 'b';
// prettier-ignore-end
```

In both cases it gets transformed into:

```js
const a = 'a';
const b = 'b';
```

So how to ignore a block of code?

Comment: The comments `prettier-ignore-start` and `prettier-ignore-end` are only supported in Markdown files.

Comment: Support or contribute to this feature: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5287

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Sometimes multiple statements can be wrapped in a block with `// prettier-ignore` in front of it:

```js
// prettier-ignore
{
abcRouter('/api/abc', server);
xRouter  ('/api/x', server);
}
```

Of course, that doesn't make sense for block-level `const` declarations, but you wrote that was not your actual code and just an example. So that's a solution that works in some but not in all cases. Overall, the strategy is to wrap multiple things in one thing that can be `prettier-ignore`d.

Another option is to move all the code you don't want to format (e.g., because it's generated) to a separate file excluded by `.prettierignore`.

`prettier-ignore-start` and `prettier-ignore-end` are supported [only in Markdown](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#markdown).

Comment: Weird they've only made `prettier-ignore-start` and `prettier-ignore-end` available for markdown.

Comment: @aderchox It's not easy at all to implement it for other languages as Prettier works with AST nodes, not with lines.

Answer (score 25):

You can ignore a code block is not supported at the moment, your option is is to only use `// prettier-ignore`

example below:

```js
// prettier-ignore
const a = 'a';
const b = 'b';

// prettier-ignore
function xyz() {
 console.log({a, b})
}
```

known issue -> https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5287

Docs -> https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript

Comment: Doesn't work for blocks

Answer (score 18):

You can ignore the whole method

```
// prettier-ignore
function myFunc() {
    const a = 'a'; const b = 'b';
    return a + b;
}
```

Actually I tried only on typescript. But I think should works on JS as well.

Comment: This works on blocks. I've tried on `functions` and `switch` blocks.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why `// prettier-ignore` does not work here is that `// prettier-ignore` will exclude the **next node in the abstract syntax tree** from formatting (see https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html).

In your case the next node would only be `const a = 'a';`. For instance,

```
// prettier-ignore
const a = 
  'a';
```

would be preserved after formatting.

If you want to keep both assignments in one line without changing the prettier configuration for your whole file, you could use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) if you are using es6 or node:

```
const [a, b] = ["a", "b"];
```

Comment: Or `const a = 'a', b = 'b';`

Comment: Well, actually this was just a minimal example, I'm really curious how to really ignore multiple things.

Answer (score 8):

It sucks, but this isnt currently supported.

While this doesnt work for OP's example, one option is to add the `prettier-ignore` comment to the *start of each line* to be ignored, using the `/* */` comment style, eg.

```
/* prettier-ignore */ import { SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB, SomeTypeC } from './some-long-folder-name/super-long-import';
/* prettier-ignore */ import { someFnA, someFnB, someFnC, } from './another-long-folder-name/super-long-import';
```

In my opinion, this is easier on the eyes than the alternatives;

Letting prettier reformat the imports:

```
import {
    SomeTypeA,
    SomeTypeB,
    SomeTypeC,
} from './some-long-folder-name/super-long-import';
import {
    someFnA,
    someFnB,
    someFnC,
} from './another-long-folder-name/super-long-import';
```

Specifying the `// prettier-ignore` comment above each import:

```
// prettier-ignore
import { SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB, SomeTypeC } from './some-long-folder-name/super-long-import';
// prettier-ignore
import { someFnA, someFnB, someFnC, } from './another-long-folder-name/super-long-import';
```

Answer (score 0):

**To disable the auto line break in the VS code.**

Open vs code => Code => Preferences => Settings => In the search field type: Prettier
Now from the provided Prettier settings, choose the Prettier: Print Width

r/vscode - To disable the auto line break in the VS code.
Screenshot

And Instead of 80, you can make it a big number. Eg: 999999
Now you don't have to worry about the line break.

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/lkz3d7/to_disable_the_auto_line_break_in_the_vs_code/

Answer (score -2):

According to its documentation, ESLint utilizes the configuration file `.eslintrc.json`. It is used to apply specific settings to ESLint.

If you wish to disable ESLint, you can delete this file (`.eslintrc.json`) under your project root directory.

You can find the documentation of ESLint at this [link](https://eslint.org/).

You can find the documentation of ESLint built-in rules at this [link](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/)

This is a sample content of `.eslintrc.json`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'node', 'prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:node/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'warn',
    'node/no-missing-import': 'off',
    'node/no-empty-function': 'off',
    'node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax': 'off',
    'node/no-missing-require': 'off',
    'node/shebang': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 'off',
    quotes: ['warn', 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    'node/no-unpublished-import': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};
```