# Prettier/VS Code adding a space before !important in CSS, causing it to break in WordPress

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier

I use VS Code for custom css I write in WordPress to have version control on it and when VS Code runs `formatOnSave` (which I generally love) in the CSS files, it inserts a space before `!important`, which when you're writing CSS over WordPress themes and page builders... is a must.

For example, it will change `padding-bottom: 0px!important;` to `padding-bottom: 0px !important;` which in some contexts (in particular in WordPress), will break it.

Is there a way to disable just this or customize just this? The rest of the formatting I very much like.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what you can do is add comments into your File which will disable prettier for a bunch of different reasons.

You can have prettier just not run full stop for a file: [Disable prettier for a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876638/disable-prettier-for-a-single-file)

But also you can dig deeper into the documentation and ignore certain lines, even adding in a ruleset:

https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/configure-prettier-in-vscode/

Also you can setup custom rulesets which might be helpful for you:

[How to make Prettier to ignore a block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259151/how-to-make-prettier-to-ignore-a-block-of-code)